# how to post data to another server through node js

Tags: node.js

As i am new to node js not getting how to hold multiple data coming from the DyanmoDB and POST it to another SERVER, i am trying like this, please help me with some logics ....
    'use strict';

```
var http = require('http');

console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    //event.forEach(function(event){
        console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
        var value1 =  event.key1;
        console.log(value1);

        var headers = {
            "Copntent-Type" : 'application/JSON'
        };
        var options = {
            url : "http://www.example.com/syncData.php",
            method : "POST",
            headers : headers,
            body     : data
        };
        request(options, function(error, response, body){
            console.log("Sending");
            postData(value1, end, end+1000);
        });
```

its giving error :

{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 61712ab7-d956-11e6-be00-bd64296711ef Process exited before completing request"
}

Answer (score 0):

make sure you make server listening to a port, or else it will end its process.

```
http.createServer(YOUR_APP_GOES_HERE)
.listen(PORT)
```